# How do I get Expo to prompt my app for "Always" Location Permission?

Tags: ios, react-native, permissions, geolocation, expo

I'm developing an `iOS` app using Expo. My app needs Location permission in order for geofencing to work when the app is not in use. I've followed Expo's documentation for Location Permission and provided `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription`, `NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription`, and `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` descriptions in my `app.json`. But when my app prompts the user for location permissions the options given are While Using App, Allow Once, or Don't Allow.

How can I get my app to prompt for Always Allow?

Comment: This is how iOS 13 behaves. When you ask for always permission, the user sees a prompt for when in use.  Your app then receives provisional always permission. After some time the user will be prompted to upgrade your apps permission to always. You should watch the WWDC 2019 video on what’s new in location services for more details

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot!

Answer (score 4):

In iOS 13, Apple changed the way that "Always allow" location permissions work.

[image]

The Always Allow option, which grants an app “background” location access, has been removed from the initial location permissions prompt. Instead, users can select Keep Only While Using (aka “foreground” permission) or select a new option,Allow Once. So how does an app then get upgraded to “background” location permission? If the user continues to use the app, iOS 13 will now automatically and periodically prompt to upgrade location permissions from While Using to Always Allow.